# Error Debugging c++ "launch: program 'C:\Users\...a.exe does not exist" help needed VS code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have freshly started programming and notably c++. I use VS code and windows 10.

My compiler is correctly installed and I can run and compile code properly. I can also use the debugger usually, except that I have received a code that I want to take a look at but I have trouble with debugging. Indeed a window pop up with the following message:

```
launch: program 'C\Users\...\Code\a.exe does not exist
```

Here is my launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }

    ]
}
```

So I can't understand why I can usually debug files but here it wouldn't work. Seems like it is looking for a.exe file eventhough the file I try to debug is called "main.cpp" so I'm confusing.

I'd like to mention also that I'm not successfully building the file itself (there are some mistake I'm not able to fix yet).

Some help would be much appreciated ! Thanks !

Antoine

Comment: Did the program build successfully? Please [edit] your question to show us the full and complete build output (copy-pasted as text).

Comment: Edit: I have now the boost library installed and no, it still doesn't build successfully. Would it be the reason ? Isn't debugging principle to fix mistakes that stops the code from building properly ?

Comment: Debugging is a way to test, check and step through an existing program. If it doesn't build, then you're fixing build errors, not debugging.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I suggest you delete this question, and post a new question about the actual build errors you get, and ask for help with them instead.

Comment: The files you are debugging is not `main.cpp` it is the **executable** that you create when you compile and link your program that you are trying to debug. I have no idea what that file is called (I can't look over your shoulder) but clearly it is not called `a.exe`. It's likely called something.exe but you need to look at your build settings to find out what that something is. Incidentally if you have just started you could not have picked a worse IDE IMHO. VSCode is hard for beginners.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers ! It take great consideration of them and will first proceed by fixing my code and run it properly, then see if I can debug. If yes, I'll delete the question, if not I'll edit this one and wait for new answers.

PS: @john which IDE would you advise for beginners then ? (That could run c, c++ and python)

Comment: @Antoine On Windows I would pick Visual Studio (which is a completely different beast than Visual Studio Code, I imagine we have MS marketing dept to thank for that). It can run C, C++, python and others.

Comment: Ok thanks ! 
Concerning the debugging problem, after so edit on the code (essentially removing buggy parts) I can now build/run the code successfully, however, still not possible to debug with the same message error..
That is confusing since, again, I can debug with other files, but that are not located in the same directory (can it be the reason ?)